# AWS Lambda Function does not get credentials from ENV variables (invalid security token)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, credentials, sam

I have a small lambda function written in Ruby that works on AWS but shows `ERROR: The security token included in the request is invalid` locally.

The purpose of this function is to read something from DynamoDB table. Here are the important parts of the function:

```rb
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-dynamodb'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  p 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ' + ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  p 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ' + ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

  dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-north-1')

  ...

  dynamodb.get_item(payload).item

  ...
end
```

When I try to invoke the function locally using `sam local start-api` I'm getting this:

```sh
START RequestId: 56d1c0f0-cad8-45b8-9a95-344c06f0aea4 Version: $LATEST
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: AKI**************TPW"
"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 1ew****************************AAn"
Error raised from handler method
{
  "errorMessage": "The security token included in the request is invalid",
  "errorType": "Function<Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-dynamodb-1.63.0/lib/aws-sdk-dynamodb/plugins/simple_attributes.rb:119:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:22:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:19:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:26:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/request_callback.rb:71:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:12:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:24:in `call'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.121.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:72:in `send_request'",
    "/var/runtime/gems/aws-sdk-dynamodb-1.63.0/lib/aws-sdk-dynamodb/client.rb:3314:in `get_item'",
    "/var/task/units.rb:29:in `unit'"
  ]
}
END RequestId: 56d1c0f0-cad8-45b8-9a95-344c06f0aea4
REPORT RequestId: 56d1c0f0-cad8-45b8-9a95-344c06f0aea4  Init Duration: 0.06 ms  Duration: 685.33 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB 
Lambda returned empty body!
```

As you can see `ENV` variables are set correctly because they are being printed to the console.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#initialize-instance_method) it should be enough to set those two `ENV` variables but looks like I'm missing something.

When I change the instantiation from

```rb
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-north-1')
```

to

```rb
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'eu-north-1', credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']))
```

Then all of a sudden lambda function connects to DynamoDB without problems.

How to make the function connect to DynamoDB locally? Assuming that I don't want to pass `:credentials` explicitly because this would break the function on AWS (because on AWS it connects to dynamodb using `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to pass AK/SK via your application ?
SAM uses your AWS Cli configuration in order to connect to DynamoDB. So normally, your application should be able to connect to DynamoDB if your local AK/SK are valid and you have the right IAM role to access your DynamoDB table.
On the other hand, on aws, lambda needs IAM role with DynamoDB access so no need for AK/SK as environment variables.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass AK/SK to my app, but that's the only way that works for me when doing `sam local start-api`. If I omit `credentials` and rely on CLI to find the credentials automatically, then all of a sudden I get `invalid security token` error, even though I have put AK/SK as my environment variables.